# error Incorrect syntax near

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had Registration form and I had in this form text box for username ,and when I test the web form I added this user in text box user name (Kaz'em) and I had this error

(Incorrect syntax near 'em'.
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.)

```
public bool RegisteredUser()
{
    bool Return = false;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ElarabyGroup"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Count(UserName) From [Registeration] Where [Registeration].UserName = '" + RegisteredUserName + "'", con);
    con.Open();
    if (int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()) > 0)
        Return = true;
    con.Close();
    return Return;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you're including user-provided data directly in your SQL.

### Don't do that.

Use a [parameterized query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) instead, setting the value from the text box as one of the parameter values instead. That way you keep the "data" part of your query away from the "code" part of your query.

You're lucky that it was just a syntax error here, instead of [little Bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)...

Answer (score 0):

You are exposed to SQL Injection attack and  it can harm like anything.

Try Method suggested by Mr.Skeet

Answer (score 0):

I will go with Jon, but you can try this also `select * from [Table] where [ColumnName]= N'Kaz'em'`

here it means it will also look for  special characters.